# Install 64 bit Centos on 32 bit windows 7 using Oracle Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos, 64-bit

I am installing 64 bit Centos image using Oracle VM VirtualBOx. 
My computer Hardware architecture is 64 bit but the OS that i have on my computer is windows 7 32 bit.

When i start installing Centos image using Orcale VM VirtualBOx it shows blank black screen. Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox [requires Intel VT extensions on a 64-bits processor](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests) to run 64-bits operating systems. It is not able to emulate all the 64-bits CPU just by software. Thus, you cannot use it to run a 64-bits CentOS on your 32-bits machine.

There are other applications that can emulate all of a system. For instance, you can use [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/) to run an OS for a different architectures, e.g. for ARM CPUs. The Android Emulator for AMD uses this approach. The problem is that OSs running in such way will be very slow.